Blazor WASM - How do I register the access token when I have authenticated the user using javascript?
I have a Blazor WASM website where I need to authenticate using Auth0 thru JavaScript.  The user is given a window where they sign into Auth0.
I can make the call successfully and I get back the following data:
{
  accessToken: STRING,
  idToken: STRING,
  scope: STRING,
  error: STRING,
  refreshToken: STRING 
}

How do I take these tokens and turn authenticate the user in the app?

You could try this below code to store the token the local storage:
wwwroot/auth.js:
window.auth0Client = null;

window.initializeAuth0 = async function (domain, clientId) {
    try {
        auth0Client = await createAuth0Client({
            domain: "your-domain",
            client_id: "your-client-id",
            audience: "https://myapi.local", // Use the API identifier here
            cacheLocation: 'localstorage',
            useRefreshTokens: true,
            authorizationParams: {
                scope: "openid profile email offline_access"
            }
        });

        console.log("Auth0 initialized successfully");
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error initializing Auth0", error);
    }
};

window.login = async function () {
    if (!auth0Client) {
        console.error("Auth0 client is not initialized.");
        return;
    }
    try {
        await auth0Client.loginWithPopup();
        const isAuthenticated = await auth0Client.isAuthenticated();
        if (isAuthenticated) {
            const accessToken = await auth0Client.getTokenSilently();
            localStorage.setItem("accessToken", accessToken);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Login failed", error);
    }
};

window.getAccessToken = function () {
    return localStorage.getItem("accessToken");
};

window.refreshToken = async function () {
    if (!auth0Client) {
        console.error("Auth0 client is not initialized.");
        return;
    }
    try {
        const newAccessToken = await auth0Client.getTokenSilently();
        localStorage.setItem("accessToken", newAccessToken);
        return newAccessToken;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Token refresh failed", error);
    }
};

appsettings.json:
{
  "Auth0": {
    "Domain": "",
    "ClientId": ""
  }
}

Login.razor:
@page "/login"
@using System.Net.Http.Headers
@inject HttpClient Http
@inject IJSRuntime JS
@inject AuthService AuthService

<h3>Blazor Auth0 Authentication</h3>
<button @onclick="AuthenticateUser">Login</button>

<p>@(IsAuthenticated ? "Authenticated" : "Not Authenticated")</p>

@code {
    private bool IsAuthenticated = false;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        // Initialize Auth0 client
        await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("initializeAuth0", "domain", "client-id");

        // Try to retrieve the access token from local storage
        var accessToken = await JS.InvokeAsync<string>("getAccessToken");
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken))
        {
            Http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
            IsAuthenticated = true;
        }
    }

    private async Task AuthenticateUser()
    {
        await AuthService.Login();
        IsAuthenticated = AuthService.IsAuthenticated;
    }
}

AuthService.cs:
using Microsoft.JSInterop;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

public class AuthService
{
    private readonly IJSRuntime _js;
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public AuthService(IJSRuntime js, HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _js = js;
        _httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    public bool IsAuthenticated { get; private set; }

    public async Task Login()
    {
        await _js.InvokeVoidAsync("login");
        var accessToken = await _js.InvokeAsync<string>("getAccessToken");

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken))
        {
            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
            IsAuthenticated = true;
        }
    }

    public async Task RefreshAccessTokenIfNeeded()
    {
        var newAccessToken = await _js.InvokeAsync<string>("refreshToken");

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(newAccessToken))
        {
            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", newAccessToken);
            IsAuthenticated = true;
        }
    }
}

Program.cs:
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthService>();

In the above code:
By using the auth.js file, we can configure the Auth0 client and manage token refreshes. This file includes code to initialize Auth0, handle login, and store the access token in localStorage for later use.The code in window.login = async function () {...} allows the user to log in via a popup window. Upon successful login, it retrieves the accessToken silently and stores it in localStorage using localStorage.setItem("accessToken", accessToken);. This makes the token accessible for future API requests and page reloads.To authenticate the user within the Blazor app, we first check if an accessToken exists in localStorage. If an accessToken is present, this indicates the user is authenticated. This check can happen in Blazor components or services that need to verify the user’s authentication status, such as AuthService.In the AuthService, we track the user’s authentication status and set the authorization header for the HttpClient when needed. This way, each request to protected APIs automatically includes the accessToken, allowing authenticated access.
Result:

